# How do I stay in the same line after getting an input from the user using Scanner?

Tags: java

I am using java and cannot figure out what command I can use to stay in the same line after getting an input from user. I only found how to stay in the same line  before requesting an input ie. using the print command instead println.

Comment: You need to realise that Java's command line interface is very limited and that kind of functionality isn't really supported.  You could try printing the backspace character, but you'll need to know how many characters were input and how the system handles the new line (does it include the carriage return or not). Alternatively, if you really want more control, you could look into Java based bindings for Curses or other such libraries

Comment: Ok. Thankyou very much! @MadProgrammer